# Automate the Boring Stuff with Python: Comma Code working but seems too simple

Tags: python, list

I am currently working on the project named in the title and was wondering if my code makes sense. It seems much simpler than others here, so I am wondering if I am missing anything.

```
def comma(list):
    for items in list:
        if items == list[-1]:
            print('and ' + items)
        else:
            print(items + ', ', end='')
        
        
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
comma(spam)
```

Output: `apples, bananas, tofu, and cats`

Comment: What is your question? We can't know what your building and thus missing.

Comment: Try it with `['alpha', 'beta', 'alpha']`

Comment: And `['alpha']`.

Comment: I am building a function that takes in a list of any size, separates each item with a comma, with the last item getting 'and' attached to it as well.

Comment: khelwood, I see the issue. I know I need a conditional statement to fix it, but am unsure of what to do.

Comment: So you want something like the result of `return data[0] if len(data) == 1 else ', '.join(data[:-1]) + f' and {data[-1]}'`? I changed the name `list` to `data`, because you overwrite the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) with your code. And you might want to add a check for an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your solution.

- If there are repeated values in the list:

```
>>> comma(["foo", "bar", "baz", "bar"])
foo, and bar
baz, and bar
```

- If the list contains one item:

```
>>> comma(["foo"])
and foo
```

I'd do it this way:

```py
def comma(lst):
    if not lst:  # No items in list
        return
    if len(lst) == 1:  # Only one item in list
        print(lst[0])
        return

    # Join all items except the last item with a comma, then append the last item
    print(f'{", ".join(lst[:-1])}, and {lst[-1]}')
```